# quantmod ... unable to get OHLCV symbol data for current day

Tags: r, quantmod

I am not able to get OHLCV data from yahoo for current day using Quantmod `getSymbols()` call. The data exists on yahoo and can also see today's OHLCV data in my charting platform. As workaround I got today's EOD quote from yahoo using `getQuote(..)` call. But when I tried to append this to the downloaded symbol data via rbind, the data object gets populated with NULLs.

I appreciate any suggestions on either how to append the today's quote to the downloaded historic symbol data or any R API's I can call after market hours to get symbol EOD (OHLCV data) including for today. Thanks.

```
library(quantmod)
library(blotter) 
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

getSymbols("SPY")
spy.quote = getQuote("SPY", what = yahooQuote.EOD)

> tail(SPY, n=3)
           SPY.Open SPY.High SPY.Low SPY.Close SPY.Volume SPY.Adjusted
2012-10-25   142.02   142.28  140.57    141.43  134457400       141.43
2012-10-26   141.30   141.84  140.39    141.35  146023500       141.35
2012-10-31   141.85   142.03  140.68    141.35  103341300       141.35

> spy.quote
             Trade Time   Open   High    Low  Close    Volume
SPY 2012-11-01 04:00:00 141.65 143.01 141.52 142.83 100990760

> SPY = rbind(SPY, spy.quote)
> tail(SPY, n=3)
          SPY.Open SPY.High SPY.Low SPY.Close SPY.Volume SPY.Adjusted
          NULL     NULL     NULL    NULL      NULL       NULL               
          NULL     NULL     NULL    NULL      NULL       NULL        
spy.quote NULL     NULL     NULL    NULL      NULL       NULL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the quote data from a `data.frame` to an `xts` object and add a column for Adjusted price.  Then you can `rbind`.

```
getSymbols("SPY", src='yahoo', to='2012-10-31')
spy.quote = getQuote("SPY", what = yahooQuote.EOD)

# convert to xts
xts.quote <- xts(spy.quote[, -1], as.Date(spy.quote[, 1])) # use Date for indexClass
xts.quote$Adjusted <- xts.quote[, 'Close'] # add an Adjusted column

tail(rbind(SPY, xts.quote), 3)
           SPY.Open SPY.High SPY.Low SPY.Close SPY.Volume SPY.Adjusted
2012-10-26   141.30   141.84  140.39    141.35  146023500       141.35
2012-10-31   141.85   142.03  140.68    141.35  103341300       141.35
2012-11-01   141.65   143.01  141.52    142.83  100995568       142.83
```